# Mongo Scala Driver Collection Does Not Update Document

Tags: mongodb, scala, mongo-scala-driver

I'm able to insert, read, and delete but I cannot get either updateOne or updateMany to modify documents.

I'm using MongoDB 3.2.7 with libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb.scala" %% "mongo-scala-driver" % "1.1.1"

```
def read() = {
val query = Document("title" -> "Text Tiling")
methods.find(query).subscribe(
  (method: Document) => update(method.toJson()),                              // onNext
  (error: Throwable) => Logger.debug(s"Query failed: ${error.getMessage}"),   // onError
  () => Logger.debug("onComplete")                                            // onComplete
)}

def update(jsonSting:String): Unit = {
Logger.debug("update() " + jsonSting)

Logger.debug(methods.find().first().toString)
val observer = new Observer[UpdateResult] {
  override def onSubscribe(subscription: Subscription): Unit = {
    Logger.debug("onSubscribe: " + subscription.toString)
  }
  override def onComplete: Unit = {
    Logger.debug("onComplete")
  }
  override def onError(e: Throwable): Unit = {
    Logger.debug("onError: " + e.getMessage)
  }
  override def onNext(doc: UpdateResult) {
    Logger.debug("onNext")
  }
}

val filter = Document("title" -> "Text Tiling")
val mod = Document("$set" -> Document("reputation" -> 5))
val result = methods.updateOne(filter,mod).subscribe(observer)
Logger.debug("result: " + result)}
```

Here are the logs:

[debug] application - update() { "_id" : { "$oid" : "5759542a4e0bf602adcab149" }, "title" : "Text Tiling", "reputation" : 0 }

[debug] application - org.mongodb.scala.ObservableImplicits$BoxedObservable@61ddc581

[debug] application - onSubscribe: org.mongodb.scala.ObservableImplicits$BoxedSubscription@6252b659

[debug] application - result: ()

[debug] application - onComplete

Answer (score 2):

Calling request on the subscription worked for me. The other events were then called after.

```
override def onSubscribe(subscription: Subscription): Unit = {
    subscription.request(1)
  }
```

[debug] application - onNext

[debug] application - onComplete!

Answer (score 0):

```scala
val filter : Bson = new Document(“key”, “old_value”) 
val newValue : Bson = new Document(“key” ,”new_value”)
val updateOperationDocument : Bson = new Document("$set", newValue)
val collection = db.getCollection(“collection_name”)
collection.updateOne(filter, updateOperationDocument)
```